# FileReader.onprogress chunk size

Tags: javascript, html

How does your browser decide how often to fire the `FileReader.onprogress` event? I'm doing some processing inside of this event and I think it's firing more often that I'd like. I want bigger chunks. Is there a way to tell it to fire less often?

Sample code:

```
_.each(dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files, function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var pos = 0;
    var startTime = +new Date();
    var xxh = XXH();

    reader.onprogress = function(progress) {
        var length = progress.loaded - pos;
        var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result, pos, length);
        pos += length;

        xxh.update(arr);

        if (progress.lengthComputable) {
            console.log('hashing', (progress.loaded / progress.total * 100).toFixed(1) + '%');
        }
    };

    reader.onload = function() {
        var arr = new Uint8Array(reader.result, pos);
        xxh.update(arr);
        var hash = xxh.digest().toNumber();

        var elapsed = +new Date() - startTime;
        console.info("computed hash", xxh.digest().toNumber(), 'for file', file.name, 'in', elapsed, 'ms');
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I happen to come across this old question while looking into another issue.
You probably don't need a solution anymore, but this may help future visitors.

You should slice the File into smaller Blobs so you can specify the exact size you want.

```
function hashFile(file, chunkSize, callback) {
  var hash = XXH();
  var size = file.size;
  var offset = 0;
  var chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);

  var hashChunk = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // Increment hash
      hash.update(e.target.result);

      // Update offset for next chunk
      offset += chunkSize;

      // Hash next chunk if available
      if(offset < size) {
        // Splice the next Blob from the File
        chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
        // Recurse to hash next chunk
        hashChunk();
      // Done hashing
      } else {
        // Report digest
        callback.call(file, hash.digest().toString(16));
      }
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
  };

  // Start hashing chunks
  hashChunk();
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/nococoqa/5/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Does `file.slice` make an actual copy of the data? Or does it just give you a "view" into the file data? I imagine the former would be slower than reading it as-is.

Comment: Blob and File objects are immutable, they should reference the same byte array. Even if you take a performance hit, you're saving memory by not loading the entire file into memory. Once a chunk is hashed it gets picked up by the GC. This allows you to hash multi GB files.

Comment: I didn't think `readAsArrayBuffer` read the whole thing into memory -- I thought that was the purpose of `onProgress`. That might explain why my larger files were taking so long, or why there was some latency on startup. I'll have to give your solution a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: @Syntax how can we use those reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk) to src of `img src= 'image-path'` . for displaying image using chunk?